# Issue with dynamic libraries

Tags: linker, g++, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I've compiled source file on host-machine:

```
g++ -I./source/utils -m32 ./source/services/library_version_info.cpp -o version_info $DAALROOT/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_core.so $DAALROOT/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_thread.so -ltbb -liomp5 -lpthread -ldl

# echo $DAALROOT
# /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/
```

When I'm trying to invoke this on target-machine I get such error:

```
./version_info: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

# echo $DAALROOT
# /media/sdcard/daalroot/daal
```

`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on target-machine contains path to `libdaal_core.so`, but program does not see that. How can I fix this error?

upd. host g++: 5.4.0, target: 4.9.1

upd2.

```
ldd version_info
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xb77db000)
    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_core.so => not found
    /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_thread.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x4332e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x43221000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x42e7d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x43003000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x42e50000)

env LD_DEBUG=all ./version_info
       408:
       408: file=/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_core.so [0];  needed by ./version_info [0]
./version_info: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin/libdaal_core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/media/sdcard/daalroot/daal/lib/ia32_lin:/media/sdcard/daalroot/daal/../tbb/lib/ia32_lin/gcc4.4
```

Comment: are you sure your target is the same platform, i.e. ia32, not x86_64

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes it's 100%.

Comment: did you try `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, the same error.

Comment: also, make sure you have the same libc

Comment: @MarcusMüller host has g++ 5.4.0, target g++ 4.9.1.

Comment: well, that doesn't necessarily work. They might have different ABI, so your program might not be compatible with the library compiled with a different compiler.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, however. Add the GCC version information to your question, so that other might bring in their experience!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've recompiled it by g++-4.9, this does not help.

Comment: You can use `env LD_DEBUG=all ./version_info` and `ldd version_info` on the target machine to see what's going on. Have you also specified /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/daal/lib/ia32_lin in the target machine LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If so, please remove it and keep only /media/sdcard/daalroot/daal

Comment: @jclin I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
g++ -I./source/utils -m32 ./source/services/library_version_info.cpp -o version_info -l daal_core -l daal_thread -ltbb -liomp5 -lpthread -ldl
```

Comment: The best practice is to use `-L/lib/path -lddal_core` to link a shared library like your update. I've tried with GCC 4.9.x and found it will embed the full path of the shared library to the executable (and you can check it by `ldd`). So whatever your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is specified to another place or even empty, the OS always knows how to load the former shared library by the embedded full path. The similar behavior is `g++ -Wl,--rpath,/lib/path -L/lib/path -lddal_core ...` which embed the default shared library path to the executable.